# Implode all the properties of a given name in an array of object - PHP

Tags: php, csv, implode, arrays

Is there a way to implode the values of similar objects contained in an array?  I have an array of objects:

```
$this->inObjs
```

and I'd like a comma separated string of each of their `messageID` properties:

```
$this->inObjs[$i]->messageID
```

Is there an elegant way to do this or am I going to have to `MacGyver` a solution with `get_object_vars` or `foreachs` or something similar?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$messageIDArray;
foreach($this->inObjs as $obj){
   $messageIDArray[] = $obj->messageID;
}

$string = implode(',',$messageIDArray);
```

Comment: he said he knows about foreach

Comment: I did not know what solution he did find, so I wrote mine. just a word foreach doesn't mean anything to me...

Comment: the first line should be
`$messageIDArray = [];`

Answer (score 4):

```
$allMessageID = '';
foreach ($this->inObjs as $objectDetail) :
    $allMessageID[] = $objectDetail->messageID;
endforeach;

$allMessageID_implode = implode(",", $allMessageID);

echo $allMessageID_implode;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can modify the class, you can implement __toString:

```
class MyObject {
    private $messageID = 'Hello';
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->messageID;
    }
}
// ...
$objectList = array(new MyObject, new MyObject);
echo implode(',', $objectList);
// Output: Hello,Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I found is using [array_map](http://php.net/array_map)

```
$messageIDs = array_map( function($yourObject) { return $yourObject->messageID; }, $this->inObjs );
$string = implode(", ", $messageIDs );
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually make a Helper for this situation, and use it like this

```
function GetProperties(array $arrOfObjects, $objectName) {
     $arrProperties = array();
     foreach ($arrOfObjects as $obj) {
         if ($obj->$objectName) {
              $arrProperties[] = $obj->$objectName;
         }
     }
     return $arrProperties;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two liner:

```
array_walk($result, create_function('&$v', '$v = $v->property;'));
$result = implode(',', $result);
```

Or:

```
array_walk($result, function(&$v, &$k) use (&$result) { $v = $v->name; } );
$result = implode(',', $result);
```

Where `$v->property` is your object property name to implode.

Also see [array_map()](http://php.net/array_map).

Comment: Why am I seeing `, &$k` and `use (&$result)` here?  Please revisit this post.  I want to use this page to close another.